# How to get a list of characters for a specific language?

Tags: android

is there a way in android to get a list of all characters from the alphabet for a specific language ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a method for that. Instead, you can view a list of alphabets and collation orders of languages [here](http://developer.mimer.com/charts/index.tml).

Then, store them in an array using this way.

```
char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
```

Comment: thanks for the link, i was actually wondering if it's possible to get collations list from somewhere without having to make them myself